# How to refresh Kendo Scheduler after setting data source?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm setting the data source of my Kendo Scheduler using the setDataSource() method, passing in a new instance of the kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource object.  I'm not using a transport, I'm setting the data property directly.  It all works, except for one problem: the events don't appear immediately.  Instead, I have to manually change months, going once backwards and then forwards before the view refreshes.

I'm a bit baffled by this behaviour, despite the fact that I am calling the refresh() method after setting the data source.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#methods-refresh

Refreshes the Scheduler rendering using the current data items.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you tried using kendo forums ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was calling setDataSource too soon after creating the Kendo Scheduler.  I used a setTimeout() with 100ms and everything works perfectly.  Big of an ugly hack.  Still interested to know if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The setTimeout() method may not guarantee that the widget will be refreshed at the right time.

Take a look at the destroy() method of the Scheduler widget.

> **destroy**
>
> Prepares the widget for safe removal from DOM. Detaches all event handlers and removes jQuery.data attributes to avoid memory leaks. Calls destroy method of any child Kendo widgets.

Calling this method means that we can safely empty the `<div>` element which contains the Scheduler using jQuery. After that, we can create a new Kendo Scheduler.

Example:

```
var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
scheduler.destroy();
$("#scheduler").empty();
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    date: Date.now(), // The current date of the scheduler
    dataSource: yourNewDataSource, // The updated data source
    views: [
        "month"
    ]
});
```